# “Sorry, ubuntu 13.04 has experienced an internal error”

Tags: 13.04

[image]

I am not sure what is causing this problem occurs every time at the start after booting.

Bug reported

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1178564

Comment: How do you exactly close your machine? I experienced this when I closed it from terminal.

Comment: I shutdown in a normal way using the shutdown option bu choosing from the drop down on click of power button in the panel. I don't use terminal

Answer (score 4):

**Reason**: Apport is a debugging tool that is used to generate crash reports. This was not enabled by default in previous versions of Ubuntu 12.04. To avoid this annoying pop-up, the Apport can be disabled by force. One drawback of doing it will be that you wont see the crash report but it is safe any ways as there is hardly any actual crash or error.

**Solution**: If you seem that there isn’t any errors in your system, you may want to disable this error/crash report notification. You can do this by disabling the Apport error report notification tool, following next steps:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal and type the command: `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/apport` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the command.
2. From here the text editor apport will show up, change the value from 1 to 0 for `enable` variable to disable the apport. Save and exit the editor, then restart the system.

[image: apport]

You can always re-enable it later on if you want, by changing "enabled" from "0" back to "1", or you can enable Apport temporarily, using the following command in a [teminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
sudo service apport start force_start=1
```

**More resources**: [Apport - What is this all about?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport)

Comment: i don't want to disable the error reported. I want to know the reason and solve the error so that next time i boot i don't see the popup showing the error

Comment: I reported the bug . thought might help others who visit the post.

Comment: Source: http://itsfoss.com/how-to-solve-sorry-ubuntu-12-04-has-experienced-an-internal-error/